# external_image_list_url in TinyMce

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I can't seem to get the external_image_list_url option in TinyMCE to work. Here is my configuration code for tinyMCE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
selector: "textarea",
external_image_list_url: "/Scripts/tinymce/imagelist.ashx",
plugins: [
"advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak     spellchecker",
"searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media     nonbreaking",
"save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor"
],
});
</script>
```

And here is the output of my imagelist.ashx generic handler:

```
var tinyMCEImageList = new Array(["logo.png", "/images/gallery/logo.png"]);
```

Can someone point me in the right direction? I have checked all the URL's and they are correct :-/

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I swithed to CKEditor. I was much more simpler to integrate a file explorer.